# Is it possible to redirect to custom error message page if user makes mistake in community url?

Tags: community, global-search

When user types some invalid text in custom community URL, system redirects you to Standard Salesforce UI with error message as 'URL No Longer Exists'. But Global Search is available in this page. So external community user is able to search and access some public data which they should not see.

How could we avoid showing standard sfui if external VF site url is broken or any other issues such as 'Insufficient Privileges' occur? Any suggestions please.

Below are the screenshots of URL and Standard SFUI page,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Goto your community --> Workspaces --> Administration --> Pages --> Click Goto Force.com
```

It will show below VF pages for different situations based on the error.Based on the error VF page that you are seeing just update the content to what you want

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info @RedDevil. But our error page is not one of these. If external user types some text in the URL after domain name like this(https://domain.force.com/kjdkfbdskbksbfk), it opens the URL no longer exists error page. This error page is not mentioned in the above list.

Comment: @Arunkumar, can you put a screenshot of that page with URL in the question please

Comment: I have updated the screenshot of URL and SFUI page in question itself.